# How can I rearrange the data from database in a ListView?

Tags: android, listview, android-arrayadapter

everyone. I have an ArrayList of the data and a ListView to showing up the list of the data. Now what I want to do is rearrange the data when I press the button and sort the data in which data has the highest result.

Here is my code:

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

private TextView mTextMessage;

String[] dataDetail;
ArrayList<dataDetail> allDetail = new ArrayList<>();

ListView detailList;
final Context context = this;

final int min = 0;
final int max = 10;
final int random = new Random().nextInt((max - min) + 1) + min;

Button reorder = findViewById(R.id.arrangeId);

private BottomNavigationView.OnNavigationItemSelectedListener mOnNavigationItemSelectedListener
        = new BottomNavigationView.OnNavigationItemSelectedListener() {

    @Override
    public boolean onNavigationItemSelected(@NonNull MenuItem item) {
        switch (item.getItemId()) {
            case R.id.navigation_home:
                mTextMessage.setText(R.string.title_home);
                return true;
            case R.id.navigation_dashboard:
                mTextMessage.setText(R.string.title_dashboard);
                return true;
        }
        return false;
    }
};

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    detailList = findViewById(R.id.dataView);

    mTextMessage = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.message);
    BottomNavigationView navigation = (BottomNavigationView) findViewById(R.id.navigation);
    navigation.setOnNavigationItemSelectedListener(mOnNavigationItemSelectedListener);

    new GetData().execute();

}

private class GetData extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, ArrayList<dataDetail>> {

    protected ArrayList<dataDetail> doInBackground(Void... voids) {

        HttpURLConnection urlConnection;
        InputStream in = null;
        try {
            URL url = new URL("http://10.0.2.2:8080/projectServer/DataDetailDB?getdata=true");
            urlConnection = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
            in = new BufferedInputStream(urlConnection.getInputStream());
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        String response = convertStreamToString(in);
        System.out.println("Server response = " + response);

        try {
            JSONArray jsonArray = new JSONArray(response);
            dataDetail = new String[jsonArray.length()];

            for (int i = 0; i < jsonArray.length(); i++) {

               final String customerName = jsonArray.getJSONObject(i).get("customerName").toString();
               final String carName = jsonArray.getJSONObject(i).get("carName").toString();
               final String appointmentDate = jsonArray.getJSONObject(i).get("appointmentDate").toString();
               final String email = jsonArray.getJSONObject(i).get("email").toString();
               final String issueDescribe = jsonArray.getJSONObject(i).get("issueDescribe").toString();
               final String timeForJob = jsonArray.getJSONObject(i).get("timeForJob").toString();
               final String costForJob = jsonArray.getJSONObject(i).get("costForJob").toString();
               final String reliableOnCar = jsonArray.getJSONObject(i).get("reliableOnCar").toString();
               final String distanceJob = jsonArray.getJSONObject(i).get("distance").toString();

                dataDetail tData = new dataDetail(customerName, carName, appointmentDate, email, issueDescribe, timeForJob, costForJob, reliableOnCar, distanceJob);
                allDetail.add(tData);

                System.out.println("customername = " + customerName + "carname = " + carName + "appointmentdate = " + appointmentDate +
                    "email = " + email + "describe = " + issueDescribe + "time = " + timeForJob + "cost = " + costForJob + "reliable = " + reliableOnCar
                + "dis = " + distanceJob);

                dataDetail [i] = "Name: " + customerName + "\n" + "Appointment Date: " + appointmentDate;


                reorder.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onClick(View v) {


                        float finalResult = random * Float.parseFloat(timeForJob) + random * Float.parseFloat(reliableOnCar) +
                                random * Float.parseFloat(distanceJob) + random * Float.parseFloat(costForJob);

                        System.out.print("Test result " + finalResult + " ");

                        /* Trying to sort the data here which has the highest finalResult
                        *  will going to the top of the list */

                        allDetail = new ArrayList<String>(Arrays.asList(dataDetail));
                        Collections.sort(allDetail);

                        ArrayAdapter newList = new ArrayAdapter(context, android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, dataDetail);
                        newList.setAdapter(theList);

                    }
                });


            }

        } catch (JSONException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        return null;
    }

    protected void onPostExecute(ArrayList<dataDetail> dataDetailArrayList) {
        super.onPostExecute(dataDetailArrayList);

        ArrayAdapter theList = new ArrayAdapter(context, android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, dataDetail);
        detailList.setAdapter(theList);
    }
}

public String convertStreamToString(InputStream is) {
    java.util.Scanner s = new java.util.Scanner(is).useDelimiter("\\A");
    return s.hasNext() ? s.next() : "";
}
```

}

But when I try to use sort I get the error says it's incompatible types.

```
allDetail = new ArrayList<String>(Arrays.asList(dataDetail));
Collections.sort(allDetail);
```

The finalResult will do the calculation and get the final result for every data it retrieves from the database. And now I just want to reorder it automatically, This is the logcat:

[image: The logcat shows the data successfully retrieve and it doing the calculation as well]

Please anyone can help how can I do the rearrange for the listview?

Comment: I’m sorry I’m new here, will be more careful next time

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Collections.sort() will work. Its your problem related to how your are storing your data in list

Comment: I want to using the score from 'finaleResult'  to sort my list

Comment: just send me what json your are getting

Comment: I get something like: 02-21 11:31:42.003 19255-19279/advprog.mmu.ac.uk.schedulerapp I/System.out: Test result 219.0 customername = Wolski carname = Suzuki appointmentdate = 04/03/2019 email = Wolski@gmail.com describe = Registration plate light bulb replace required time = 5 cost = 40 reliable = 4 dis = 5
    Test result 54.0 customername = Cardinal carname = Toyota appointmentdate = 15/02/2019 email = Cardinal@gmail.com describe = Car service required time = 6 cost = 45 reliable = 6 dis = 2

Comment: its now look like json. Send me the json which you have retrivred

Comment: Server response = [{"customerName":"Josh","carName":"Toyota Aygo","appointmentDate":"01/03/2019","email":"Josh@gmail.com","issueDescribe":"The engine is down and can not initiate","timeForJob":"3","costForJob":"200","reliableOnCar":"9","distance":"7"},{"customerName":"Wolski","carName":"Suzuki","appointmentDate":"04/03/2019","email":"Wolski@gmail.com","issueDescribe":"Registration plate light bulb replace required","timeForJob":"5","costForJob":"40","reliableOnCar":"4","distance":"5"},

Comment: Should be more but characters limits

Comment: on Which field you have to sort

Comment: Like I'm using some data to do the calculation: float finalResult = random * Float.parseFloat(timeForJob) + random * Float.parseFloat(reliableOnCar) + random * Float.parseFloat(distanceJob) + random * Float.parseFloat(costForJob); Now I just want to sort the list when any data has the highest score will going to the top of the list and then go on.

Comment: But on which key u have to sort on timeForJob or distanceJob or name

Comment: Using the timForJob should be fine, is possible to using finalResult to sort the list?